# How does tensorflow keep l2_normalize constraint?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have the following graph

```
X = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 3), name="X", initial_value=np.array([[1,2,3]]))
(1) X = tf.nn.l2_normalize(X)

y = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(X))  - 2 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sin(tf.square(X)))
training_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(y)
```

`y` here is not important; what matters here is that I want to minimize the function with the constaint on L2 norm of `X`. So I add the line (1) and do one iteration:

```
fX, fy = sess.run(fetches=[X, y])
print('Variables before the step', fX, '(norm = ', np.linalg.norm(fX), ') ', fy)
sess.run(training_op)
fX, fy = sess.run(fetches=[X, y])
print('Variables after the step', fX, '(norm = ', np.linalg.norm(fX), ') ', fy)
```

The output is:

```
Variables before the step [[0.26726124 0.5345225  0.8017837 ]] (norm =  0.99999994 )  -0.90539074
Variables after the step [[0.27040556 0.5390706  0.7976739 ]] (norm =  0.99999994 )  -0.90757775
```

I wonder why the norm after the step is still equals to one. Here's my hypothesis: I am trying to minimize not `y(X)`, but `y(norm(X))` where `norm(X) =  X / sqrt(sum(X**2)`, so when `tf` computes a gradient it takes this `norm` into account and somehow because of this after the step the norm of `X` is maintained at 1 (but it it still not clear for me why).

Could you please confirm it, or explain how this actually works?